# Sometimes get a ValueError from passing a float to int() method, but not always

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

Python newbie here. I've been messing around with flow control and have come across a situation I don't quite understand related to exceptions.

In the following code I want the user to enter an integer in a given range and, in the case of non-compliance, keep asking them until they give a valid value:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(raw_input("Pick an integer between 2 and 9. "))
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter an integer!"
        continue
    else:
        if 2 <= x <= 9:
            print("Your number is {0}.").format(x)
            break
        else:
            print "That's not between 2 and 9!"
            continue
```

As far as I can tell, this code works exactly as I want it to. I've thrown every other type of input I can think of at it and it only lets you exit the loop when an integer from 2-9 is entered. *Not even floats are accepted.*

My question is, given that `int()` can be successfully called on floats,

```
>>> int(2.1)
2
```

why does this try/except construct raise the exception when the input is a `float`? If I run the code without the try/except statements and enter anything other than an integer, it throws an error and exits.

I'm running python 2.7 from windows powershell.

Comment: Because you're not calling it on a float.

Comment: what you check ist int("2.1"). That throws an exception. raw_input returns a str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `raw_input` returns a string.

Under the hood, when you call `int`, it actually calls an objects `object.__int__()` method. This is different from object to object.
For a float, this truncates a value (Rounds towards 0).
On a string, it tries to parse an `int` according to https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals (Which can't have a `.`).

Comment: Ah thank you! I hadn't considered the fact that `int` might work differently on the string returned by `raw_input` than on actual raw input. Cheers for the link, haven't looked into the effects of the lexical anlyzer at all, should be helpful to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are calling `int()` on a string that could potentially contain a period. To fix this I would recommend you change the `int()` to `float()`. This should fix your problem

```
x = float(raw_input("Pick an integer between 2 and 9. "))
```

Comment: Nono, it works perfectly! I just couldn't understand why it was catching floats when `int()` usually works just fine on floats. Didn't think about the fact that `raw_input()` was returning a string. If I used `float()` then I'd have to add an extra check to make sure that the user had entered an integer and not a float.

edit* which I should probably do anyway so that it can work on values other than those given by `raw_input()`...

thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Python you are using but if it is Python 3.0 or above you might want to carefully check the print statements in the following clips

```
except ValueError:
    print "Please enter an integer!"

else:
    print "That's not between 2 and 9!"
```

they are not formatted for 3.0  but will probably work ok if you use version 2.x
I think the other answers covered your original problem adequately so I will defer to them.. they know that area better than I.
Good Luck,
Poe